# How to prove that $S = S^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathscr{P}$ be a poset and $DM(\mathscr{P}) = \{ S \subseteq \mathscr{P} | S = S^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} \}$. Here $x \in S^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$ if and only if it is a lower bound of all upper bounds of $S$. Let $\mathcal{S} = \{ S_i | i \in I \} \subseteq DM(\mathscr{P})$. So $\mathcal{S}$ consists of sets $S_i$ that for $S_i = S_i^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$ and $S_i \subseteq \mathscr{P}$.

And let $A = \bigcup_{i \in I} S_i$.
How to prove that $A = A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$?

Only thing I've come up with is $A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} = (\bigcup_{i \in I} S_i)^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} = \bigcup_{i \in I} S_{i}^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} = \bigcup_{i \in I} S_i = A$, but I don't think this is allowed?

Answer (score 1):

The assertion is false. Let $\mathscr{P}=\Bbb R^2$, and let $\preceq$ be the partial order on $\mathscr{P}$ given by $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle\preceq\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ iff $x_0\le x_1$ and $y_0\le y_1$. Let $L_0=\{\langle 0,1\rangle\}^{\ell}$ and $L_1=\{\langle 1,0\rangle\}^\ell$. They $L_0^{u\ell}=L_0$ and $L_1^{u\ell}=L_1$, but $(L_0\cup L_1)^{u\ell}\ne L_0\cup L_1$; in fact, there is no $S\subseteq\mathscr{P}$ such that $L_0\cup L_1=S^\ell$, and $(L_0\cup L_1)^{u\ell}=\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}^\ell$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation you introduce is rather muddled (you initially describe $\mathscr{S}$ as being the set which consists of the terms $S_i$ of a tacitly given family $S$ of sets -- for only then could this notation make sense -- however we see next that $S$ is also used to refer to the union of all these terms), so I will change it for ease of understanding.

Consider an arbitrary ordered set $(A, R)$ and for any subset $X \subseteq A$ define the ''lower bound'' and ''upper bound'' operators:
$$\begin{align}
X^{\bigtriangledown}=\{y \in A|\ (\forall x)(x \in X \Rightarrow y \leqslant_R x)\}\\
X^{\bigtriangleup}=\{y \in A|\ (\forall x)(x \in X \Rightarrow y \geqslant_R x) \}
\end{align}$$
together with the operator:
$$\begin{align}
\Phi \colon \mathscr{P}(A) &\to \mathscr{P}(A)\\
\Phi(X)&=\left(X^{\bigtriangleup}\right)^{\bigtriangledown},
\end{align}$$
operator which we are going to notice is *a closure operator* in the precise sense of the following properties:

1. $\Phi$ is **isotonic** (increasing):
   $$X \subseteq Y \Rightarrow \Phi(X) \subseteq \Phi(Y)$$
2. $\Phi$ is **expansive** (or inflationary):
   $$X \subseteq \Phi(X)$$
3. $\Phi$ is an **idempotent** map:
   $$\Phi \circ \Phi=\Phi.$$

I leave up to you the task of rigorously establishing these properties, you can let me know if you have any difficulties in achieving this. The result you should be seeking to prove can be phrased in the following general manner. Let us define the collection:
$$\mathscr{F}=\left\{X \subseteq A|\ X=\left(X^{\bigtriangleup}\right)^{\bigtriangledown}\right\}$$
of all subsets of $A$ which are fixed by $\Phi$. It is then the case that **for any nonempty subset $\varnothing \neq \mathscr{M} \subseteq \mathscr{F}$ the intersection $\bigcap \mathscr{M} \in \mathscr{F}$ is also fixed by $\Phi$** (in other words, the collection of all $\Phi$-fixed subsets forms a closure system on $A$).

If we denote $T=\bigcap \mathscr{M}$, we have that $\Phi(T) \subseteq \Phi(X)=X$ for every $X \in \mathscr{M}$, by virtue of the isotony of $\Phi$. This leads immediately to $\Phi(T) \subseteq \displaystyle\bigcap_{X \in \mathscr{M}}X=T$ which combined with the inflationary character of $\Phi$ yields $\Phi(T)=T$.

The claim that an arbitrary union of subsets fixed by $\Phi$ remains itself $\Phi$-invariant will not in general be valid. The case of $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard order together with the sequence of intervals $\left(\left(-\infty, \frac{n}{n+1}\right]\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ furnishes a counterexample to such a claim.

Comment: I edited the original question so that S is only used as the union of $S_i$'s. Notice that the first S is $\mathcal{S}$, so it is a family of sets and the font is different.

Anyhow this proof should be quite short and easy, it's part of proving that Dedekind-MacNeille completion is a complete lattice.

Comment: @onm I have noticed the font difference from the very beginning and that is not the issue. The actual issue resides in the fact that in order to make sense of the notation $\{S_i|\ i \in I\}$ -- which you produce out of the blue without prior introduction of a family $S$ of subsets -- one has to assume the existence of a syntactic object called $S$ which is a family indexed by $I$ such that upon appending $i$ as a subscript you are indicating the term of index $i$ of that family. That is how the rigorous manipulation of notation regarding families works, *(to be continued)*

Comment: @onm *(cont.)* you can't have a bunch of objects $x_i$ unless you first introduce the family $x$ as an autonomous, self-standing entity. Things being so, at the point of employing the notation $\{S_i|\ i \in I\}$ you implicitly already have the character $S$ allocated to refer to this tacitly introduced family $S$ (family which is completely unrequired and only complicates syntax).

Comment: @onm *(cont2.)* In the next phrase you come forth with a *distinct* usage of the character $S$, this time to refer to the union of the $S_i$...well, $S$ can't at the same time be **the whole family** as well as the union of all its terms, can it now? As to the claim regarding unions, I shall invite you once again to contemplate the counterexample I suggested in order to convince yourself it isn't valid (the claim).

Comment: @ΑΘΩ: It is not true that ‘you can’t have a bunch of objects $x_i$ unless you first introduce the family $x$ as an autonomous, self-standing entity’, and there is absolutely nothing wrong with **onm**’s introduction of the sets $S_i$. There is also nothing wrong with letting $S=\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$. What you are asserting is flatly contrary to perfectly normal mathematical practice.

Comment: @BrianMScott While the assertion about the bunch of indexed objects should be ammended indeed to allow for some particular situations which constitute an exception (ammendment that I sought to allude to by mentioning ''in principle''), the ''perfectly normal mathematical practice'' -- which you refer to and of which I am quite aware -- is markedly unrigorous and questionable on the grounds of proper usage of the formal language of mathematics. Not to mention that in such instances it is completely pointless and unnecessary. *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @BrianMScott *(cont.)* unnecessary to introduce a family of objects satisfying a certain property, it suffices to simply speak of a subset of the parent set of all objects satisfying the respective property. Having a family in this picture plays absolutely no role -- whether syntactically or semantically -- it is a useless complication. There are lots of forms and styles of ''common mathematical practice'', which does not necessarily stand to mean they are all impeccable and without blemish.

Comment: @onm As one more remark, it is precisely the claim regarding arbitrary **intersections** (the one proved in the above answer) and *not* the incorrect one involving unions that establishes the validity of the Dedekind-MacNeille completion.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ: It is standard practice; telling someone not to use it is futile if you’re talking to an experienced mathematician and a disservice if you’re talking to anyone else. And it is certainly not ‘markedly unrigorous’. Moreover, no one in his right mind does actual mathematics in a truly formal language.

Comment: @BrianMScott  It is one of several standard practices, some of which present elements of syntactic sloppiness and others which are quite rigorous to the letter. Nevertheless, I have no intention to give ultimatums to people - be they more or less experienced - to behave in this or that way. I was simply pointing out the flaws and overall uncouthness of the notation exhibited above. Whether anyone engaged in this conversation here decides to take my remarks to mind and accordingly modify his notation style, that is his choice and his liberty.

Comment: @BrianMScott *(cont.)* Having a semantic confusion over that letter $S$ most certainly is unrigorous as is the general practice of describing the generic elements of a set as the terms of some undeclared family, especially when there is absolutely no need for any indexing, it being no more than a meaningless complication (as it is in the case above). What I meant by ''formal language'' was not writing absolutely every single step of mathematical text in set-theory formalism, but being rigorous about the general rules of syntax.